# How do you make a faucet for native assets such as NFTS on cardano?

Tags: smart-contract, nft, cardano-serialization-lib, cardano-address, faucet

im trying to make an NFT faucet  for a NFT drop. How do I make the basic faucet  is there an example that I could build upon?

Answer (score 0):

i have created this script in bash.

```
https://forum.cardano.org/t/auto-sell-and-send-tokens/94280/2
```

if you have any questions, please let me know.

the main idea is to

1. check your wallet with how many TxHash it is
2. take each TxHash and find sender
3. send to "sender" tokens or refund, based on what you want to achieve.

not so much CPU and hardware resources...
we have finished our first Sales today, with 3 different Packets.

Comment: Is there something written in Plutus for this?

Comment: still writing and learning mate :) - but i will do the best to bring ideas and guideline for this kind of solutions.

if any answer helps you, please dont forget to click on "this answer is useful" to support our try.

Comment: There's an example of a token sale in Plutus here from Lars for the Plutus Pioneer Program: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/tree/main/code/week08
and the lecture is here https://youtu.be/y5O58-NpnJ4
Maybe a good starting point for what you could be trying to achieve 

Comment: great, thank you for sharing.